# Net::HTTP Gives time out but browser visit returns data

Tags: ruby, facebook

I tried the following

```
Net::HTTP.get_print URI.parse(URI.encode('https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=mytoken', '|'))
```

(My Token is my actual token in code)

I get a `EOFError: end of file reached error`

If I visit the page with my browser it loads up a JSON page. Any idea what could be causing the error? It was working a few days ago. Can't see any changes to Facebook API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still working on it but this is what i have so far...i found a bug report with facebook on the issue: http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=225521

I can safely call

```
Net::HTTP.get_print  URI.parse(URI.encode('http://www.whyspam.me', '|'))
```

and get a responsejust fine, but i've yet to be capable of getting a response from any https site such as bankofamerica.com. I'll keep you posted, if I find anything else...hope this helps